# Unable to pull Crypto quantity_held_for_buy using robin_stocks

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pull *crypto quantities held for buy* within Robinhood using
**robin_stocks**  :

```
robin_stocks.robinhood.crypto.get_crypto_positions(info=None)
```

Above function returns all the required values except puts 0s for **quantity_held_for_buy**
I have tried this using different crypto symbols held for buy, but I only get return 0 value for the quantities held for buy.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks,
Sean